# Set registry key OUTSIDE of HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How do I set a value to the registry that is NOT in HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

```
My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("..\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\")
```

This above only puts it in a folder named `..`

Comment: That's not how the registry works; you need to be in a hive.

Comment: @SLaks Okay, : I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Open regedit and look around.  The five `HKEY_*` things are called _hives_; everything in the registry is inside them.

Comment: @SLaks Oh ok I never knew they were not just *folders* thx but is it possible to create inside em?

Comment: bad idea to mess with the registry if you do not understand it first as you can make your computer unusable really fast.  May want to do a bit of reading first.   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256986

Comment: Thank you @Sorceri it's just that you need to access the ClassesRoot to add stuff to the Windows right click menu shell but whatever guys i figured it out

Comment: @Supercoder: You can do that without needing admin by writing to `HKCU\Software\Classes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine` to access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

If that does not solve your problem, please let me know in comments.